# Hide slide(s) in a Google Docs presentation?

Tags: google-slides

Can one cherry pick slide(s) to show/hide in a presentation?  This feature seems to be missing (or it is UI-fail).

The object is to use a single slide deck as the source material for different presentations.  Say for a high-level talk I skip the minutiae while for another I use all the slides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right click on the slide and choos "Skip Slide"

Comment: Don't know why the down votes.  This is indeed now possible.  Must be a recent addition (as of Oct 2017) to Google presentations.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Ziggy Dziegman](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Uf-Ev1ThPtg) Jun 2, 2014 it is not possible at present. From your Title (singular) you might move a slide to the end of the presentation and stop presenting before it. From the body of your question (plural) you might copy the presentation and delete the slides you do not wish to show.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'll update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real native function, however this workaround works well:

Instead of using the Present button, you will change the URL by replacing everything from /edit to the end of the URL with /preview?rm=minimal

I hope that I was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the preview mode.  I wasn't aware of it.  The accepted answer is my preferred way to address my original question.